# Initializing form input from REST API response and handling user input in React

Tags: reactjs

My component has an edit form with inputs that are initialized with some default values, but I also have a useEffect hook that initializes the inputs with data from the DB using an API call.

This works fine the first time I load the component and it fetches the record's data, but if users type on a field the input's onChange function will cause the parent to update the state and as a result ALL OTHER inputs get reset with a default value. The API request isn't made again (I want this behavior to avoid repeated calls).

Not sure how I should structure this so inputs are not reset to the default values. Should I store the response to the API call in local storage and only use the default values for initialization if the local storage is empty? Is there a better way to do this?

My Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import axiosInstance from "../axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import EditTitle from "./EditTitle";
import EditDescription from "./EditDescription";


function Test(props) {
  console.log('Test Component - render')

  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    description: ""
  });

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  const { id } = useParams();
  
  async function getRecord() {
    let response = {};
    try {
      response = await axiosInstance.get('records/' + id)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      response.data = null;
    }
    
    return setFormData(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {    
    console.log('Test Component - useEffect called')
    getRecord();
  }, []);


  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    let value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : typeof e.target.value === "number" ? e.target.value : e.target.value.trim();
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: value,
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {formData &&
        <Container>
          <Typography>Editing record: {formData.title} {id}</Typography>
          <form>
            <EditTitle title={formData.title} handleChange={handleChange} />
            <EditDescription description={formData.description} handleChange={handleChange} />
          </form>
        </Container>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

The EditTitle and EditDescription components are really just wrappers around inputs. They look like this:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const EditDescription = ({description, handleChange}) => {

    console.log('EditDescription - render')

    return (
    <Box>
      <Box>
        <Typography>Description</Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <TextField
          value={description?? ""}
          multiline
          rows={4}
          name="description"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
};

export default React.memo(EditDescription);
```

Comment: Providing `formData` to the dependencies array of `handleChange` helper should fix the value reset issue. `const handleChange = useCallback(e => {[...]}, [formData]);`

https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I was trying to stop all the 'input' components from re-rendering when one of them got updated. Ended up taking the step you suggested along with passing a custom function to memo to compare props.